# Laravel Index - Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$links

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I have searched quite a bit but cannot get other solutions working for my error using pagination:[image]

It errors on the line containing `{{ $dishes->links }}`

I am trying to paginate my dish.index page.

My DishController index function looks like so:

```html
public function index()
    {
        $dishes = Dish::paginate(2);
        return view('dishes.dish_index')->with('dishes', $dishes);
    }
```

I have even attempted the method of following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e) however I don't think I understand enough about collections in order to remedy my issue.
I also attempted to use `$dishes = Dish::all()->paginate(2);` but that returns the same error.

I don't think it's directly related but I don't have a route setup with {page} either, currently I only have `Route::resource('dish', DishController::class);`. Seperate concern but possibly related?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Its `{{ $dishes->links() }}` not {{ $dishes->links }}

Comment: That provides a new error: `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist.` @JSTECH

Comment: Are you sure that in the $dishes you got the data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sorry? @wiwekchauhan
I thought you could just call links()

Comment: $dishes = Dish::paginate(2); After this line put `dd($dishes);` and check that you got the data or not.

Comment: Ah, apologies! I had since changed that line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $dishes = Dish::paginate(2);
    return view('dishes.dish_index', compact('dishes'));
}
```

View

```
{{ $dishes->links() }}
```